# Serving static files with multiple segments

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm using Rocket [multiple segments](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/requests/#multiple-segments) to serve static files, by this code:

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use std::path::PathBuf;
use rocket::response::NamedFile;
use std::path::Path;

#[get("/public/<file..>")]
fn files(file: PathBuf) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    NamedFile::open(Path::new("static/").join(file)).ok()
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/public", routes![files])
        .launch();
}
```

With the above server, requests for files at `/public/<path..>` should be handled by returning the contents of `/static/<path..>`, right?

Then on my browser, I enter the domain name along with `/public/` and a multipe-segment route path, for example, a `*.jpg` file, but it cannot serve the file:

[image: 404 error]

As far as I check, the JPG file exists. I cannot figure out what I'm missing!

### UPDATE

I also tried to use a builtin module to do so:

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use rocket_contrib::serve::StaticFiles;

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/public", StaticFiles::from("/static"))
        .launch();
}
```

But it's not working either. Not sure why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve:

1. Notice the absolute vs relative path difference: `.mount("/", StaticFiles::from("static"))` means static folder should be next to the server executable.
2. Run the server executable in the proper working directory and place `static` folder next to it.